# How to hide/show respective hive databases in hue based on USER/ROLE impersonation

Tags: hive, hue

So far till now I know about this, is there any other configuration I need to add/change.

Configure Hue as a proxy user for all other users and groups, meaning it may submit a request on behalf of any other user. Add to core-site.xml:

```
<property>
  <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hue.hosts</name>
  <value>*</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hue.groups</name>
  <value>*</value>
</property
```

Use case : 
User x should see only db1, db2
User y should see only db1

(ROLE1 is owner of db1,ROLE2 is owner of db2)

Comment: If using Sentry with HiveServer2, the available tables will automatically be displayed (all the filtering is done at the HiveServer2 level, there is no specific logic in Hue).

Answer (score 0):

Use Revoke /Grant command to user/group on hive .

```
           revoke <permissions> on table <table> from user <user or group>;
```

Then add groups/user value  on "hadoop.proxyuser.hue.groups" on "core-site.xml"